# how to add dynamically image in label with button click using rcp and swt / jface component

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, filedialog

Button click to open **FileDialog Box** and selected any image to display on specific label.

i try to set  absolute path or relative path using selected images in Label control
but not proper working dynamically.

so please help to my question solve.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: @Rüdiger Herrmann i find this solution...thanks for advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Java SWT Load and Resize Image to View or Editor at Dynamically

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

> Button click to open FileDialog Box and selected any image to display on specific label.

**ImageLoader** class are used to load images from, and save images to, a file or stream

**ImageData** class are device-independent descriptions of images

SWT's **Image** class can be used to display images in a GUI

```
package rcp_demo.Editor;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader;


public class ProductEditor extends EditorPart {

        public static final  String ID="rcp_demo.Editor.product";
        private Text text;
        private CLabel lbl_image_text;

        private static final String[] FILTER_NAMES = {
        "Images(*.jpg)","Images(*.jpeg)","Images(*.png)","All Files (*.*)"};

        // These filter extensions are used to filter which files are displayed.
        private static final String[] FILTER_EXTS = { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.*"};

    public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

        parent.setLayout(null);
        //Layout with absolute positioning components. 

        text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setBounds(25, 57, 169, 19);

        Button btnOpen = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
        btnOpen.setText("open");
        btnOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), SWT.OPEN);
            dialog.setFilterNames(FILTER_NAMES);
            dialog.setFilterExtensions(FILTER_EXTS);
            String result = dialog.open();
            if(result!=null)
               {
                   text.setText(result);
                   Image image=SWTResourceManager.getImage(result);
                   ImageData imgData = image.getImageData();
                   imgData=imgData.scaledTo(200, 200);

                   ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
                   imageLoader.data = new ImageData[] {imgData};
                   imageLoader.save(result, SWT.IMAGE_COPY);

                   System.out.println(imgData.width+"....."+imgData.height);
                   lbl_image_text.setBounds(25,88,imgData.width+10,imgData.height+10);
                   //Image size set to Label
                   //lbl_image_text.setBounds(25,88,image.getBounds().width+10,image.getBounds().height+10);
                   lbl_image_text.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(result));
               }
        }
    });
    btnOpen.setText("open");
    lbl_image_text = new CLabel(parent, SWT.Resize);
    }
}
```

The **CLabel** class provides some advanced features over the Label class.
This class can display its text label and image label at the same time.

```
    lbl_image_text.setText("Welcome");
    lbl_image_text.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("Image Path"));
```

Comment: Please look into using [`Layout`s](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html). Absolute positioning/sizing is going to get you into trouble eventually.

Comment: @Baz Layout with absolute positioning components ..Set Layout Design time(extends EditorPart)..thanks